# «Точно наверняка» — правильно ли так говорить?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, плеоназм

Из книги Людмилы Мартовой [«Первый шаг к мечте»](https://books.google.ee/books?id=zihgDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT139&lpg=PT139&dq=%D0%AF%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%94%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=0VnPF9cfBg&sig=ACfU3U3_B6HrCeZNWk0wZ2FbX2uWXDXlEQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5xdv32_bnAhVimIsKHUoZAAoQ6AEwAHoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%AF%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%94%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false):

> Я думаю, что он знает обо всех обитателях этого дома все. Он должен знать ответы на вопросы: откуда взялась Валентина, почему Липатов оставил ей деньги, отчего он так не любил своего младшего внука. (**?**) Да и на все другие вопросы он **точно наверняка** знает ответы.

*Совершенно точно, почти наверняка* — эти выражения понятны и употребляются часто. А вот "комплекс" ***точно наверняка*** меня смущает — он мне кажется избыточным.
Или все правильно? Подскажите-разъясните.
И еще. Не нужен ли в конце второго предложения вопросительный знак?

Comment: Точно наверняка — «масло масляное», потому что это синонимы

Comment: Само предложение не вопросительное, поэтому "?", по-моему, не нужен. Основная мысль в том, что он должен знать ответы на эти вопросы.

Comment: Если разделить запятой (которую мог убрать корректор издательства) эти выражения разной степени уверенности, то автора можно оправдать тем, что он предоставляет читателю выбор более точного из этих двух слов (как бы опущено "если хотите" между ними)..

Comment: Это не синонимы. Выражение вполне осмысленное именно без запятой. Первое наречие накладывается на второе и получается результат:
Точно наверняка = Точно(100%)*Наверняка (99%) = 99%
Неточно наверняка = Неточно(50%)*Наверняка (99%) = 49,5%
Наверняка точно = Наверняка(99%)*Точно (100%) = 99%
Наверняка неточно = Наверняка(99%)*Точно (50%) = 49,5%

Можно даже так: Наверняка наверняка = 99*99=... 

А вот точно точно - масло масленное

Comment: @Alex_ander: согласен! Только с поправкой, что слова надо переставить тогда: *наверняка, если хотите, точно.*

Comment: Скажем, 'точно' (как определитель второго наречия) можно заменить на синоним 'никак иначе чем как' и тогда туман рассеивается: Он никак иначе чем как наверняка знает ответы

Comment: Думаю, что можно трактовать "точно" как утверждение, основанное знании проверенных фактов, а "наверняка" как утверждение основанное на личной уверенности ("иначе и быть не может"). При имеющемся порядке слов сочетание "точно, наверняка" может выражать смысл "это точно, во всяком случае, я уверен".

Answer (score 1):

то́чно

нареч.

Соотносится по значению с прил. точный.
Прямо, как раз, ровно.

союз

Как будто, как если бы, словно.

Думаю, что здесь, в вашем предложении, мы имеем союз и второе значение — «как будто» и тогда такое употребление оправдано.

Да и на все другие вопросы он точно наверняка знает ответы (как будто наверняка знает ответы).
На эту мысль меня навели поиски в НКРЯ и похожий пример.

Comment: Полностью согласна, здесь не два наречия, а сравнительный союз в значении "как будто", "словно". Речь о том, что персонажа подозревают в знании ответов.  "Он должен знать ответы на вопросы ... Да и на все другие вопросы он точно (словно бы ) наверняка знает ответы. (Он отвечает так, как будто бы знает ответы)